# Why does my render look like this in eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, tracking

I am trying to workout a workflow from Boujou to blender but when I use EEVEE the cubes look messed up and start jittering and going transparent. Then in Cycles everything looks alright but I would really like to use EEVEE instead.

Top Pic EEVEE
Bottom Pic Cycles

[image]

[image]